# Router won't work after copying a file there through ssh

Tags: ssh, openwrt

So, I copied some scripts from my PC to my OpenWRT router's `~/bin` - which is in the `$PATH` - but I've accidentally copied them to /bin instead. And after that my router turns on, but it doesn't function: it neither distributes wifi, nor internet though cable. And because of this I can't connect to my router again.

Comment: You bricked your box. How to unbrick varies. You'll have to tell us the exact model and hardware revision of your box if you want us to Google the proper unbricking procedures for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've most likely made your primary OS image unbootable, and need to look into how to recovery mode works for (that is, how to un-brick) your exact model / hardware revision.

Go to the OpenWrt website and read up on the recovery procedures for your device.